# Android widget design - default black background

Tags: android, themes, android-widget

In the new version(s) of Android such as version 2.1, default widget (music widget, news and weather widget, youtube widget) have been restyled to use a black background with a white radial gradient at the top in the middle. I've seen other widgets starting to use the exact same background.

However, I can't find this background anywhere. The widget design guidelines (https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html) still refer to the outdated background (or frames as they are referred to on that page).

How can I get hold of that background? Ofcourse, I could try to design it myself to make it look like the default style as much as possible but that's seems stupid. :)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is stumbling over this, Google updated their design guidelines and supplied an App Widget Template Pack

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#templates